# insertBefore stops working in form If I add div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created dynamic form in which I can add as many authors as I want to.

```
<form action="uploadtodb.php" target="dummyframe" method="post" name="myform">
            <p>
            Authors last name:      <input type="text" name="authorln[]" size="32" />
            Authors first names:    <input type="text" name="authorfns[]" size="32" />
            </p>
            <p id="add_author_button">
            <button type="button" onclick="add_author()">Add new author</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="remove_author()">Remove last author</button>
            </p>
</form>
```

where function add_author() adds to **myform** new paragraph denoted below as **para**

```
document.myform.insertBefore(para, document.getElementById("add_author_button"));
```

It works perfectly, but then I wanted to add some styles to it. So I added div:

```
<form action="uploadtodb.php" target="dummyframe" method="post" name="myform">
        <div id="authors">
            <p>
            Authors last name:      <input type="text" name="authorln[]" size="32" />
            Authors first names:    <input type="text" name="authorfns[]" size="32" />
            </p>
            <p id="add_author_button">
            <button type="button" onclick="add_author()">Add new author</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="remove_author()">Remove last author</button>
            </p>
        </div>
</form>
```

After such modification buttons do not respond.

Comment: Why not style the form itself by adding a class or an id to it? You can treat the form as a container

Comment: @Erick I decided to split form into different styles. For the sake of question I extracted just authors.

Comment: `para` is no longer a child of `myform` so `document.myform.insertBefore` may no longer be functioning the way you expect.

Comment: @RJM That's right. I had tried `document.authors.insertBefore`, but it didn't work. I see that I need it to be in both `authors` and `myform`, but I am not sure how does html heredity works in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can use `document.<form name>` for forms, you can't do that for arbitrary elements like your authors `div`.  Why not just use `getElementById()`?

```
document.getElementById("authors").insertBefore(para, document.getElementById("add_author_button"));
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I was afraid that `document.getElementById("authors").(...)` may forget that it should be also in `myform`, but I checked and everything uploads to the server.